# How to resize calendar according to wear os size in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, wear-os

I want to build a time converter app for wear os android but i am unable to customize the size of calendar according to wear device size.
here is my code

```
DateTime? pickedDateTime = await showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                    initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.inputOnly,
                    firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                    lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 356)),
                    builder: (context, child) {
                      return Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 300,
                            // width: 300,
                            child: child,
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
```

and the result is
[image]